# UNIX socket for communication python - C++

Tags: python, c++, sockets, ipc

I am trying to communicate between python and C++ via UNIX socket in Windows 10 64bit. 
According to the documentation, to use UNIX sockets I need to set the family as `AF_UNIX` instead of `AF_INET`, and create a temporary local socket. This seems to be possible in Windows since last year, but I haven't found a clear explanation on how to do it. 
I currently have this setting:

**Server python**

```
HOST = '127.0.0.1'  
PORT = 5555    
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        # Do something with recv(), send()
        ....
```

**Client C++**

```
WSADATA WSAData;
SOCKET server;
SOCKADDR_IN addr;

WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &WSAData);
server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);   
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); 
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(5555);
connect(server, (SOCKADDR *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
// Do something with recv(), send()
```

Since this communication is pretty slow for my purpose, I want to do the same but using a UNIX socket. How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: I know Unix sockets are not represented by ip address + port, but I don't know how to correctly represent them in C++ and python. My example as I wrote is related to the AF_INET family

Comment: On unix/linux, for a unix-domain socket, the argument to `socket.bind` and `socket.connect` is just a string providing the path name to the socket file. I would try that initially (using an appropriate Windows path name), maybe something like: `s.bind("c:\\temp\\foo.sck")`

Comment: Also, it appears Windows supports the "abstract" name space. That is a null character followed by a name that won't show up in the filesystem anywhere, so something like: `s.bind("\x00foo")`

Answer (score 0):

For C++ you might want to refer to examples in [this post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windowswsl-interop-with-af_unix/).

For Python it is unsupported yet as of writing. See [bpo-33408](https://bugs.python.org/issue33408).